# Neighborhood calculations for outlier detection

Tags: r, algorithm, data-science, histogram, outliers

I'm using the R programming language, and I'm trying to understand the details of the following function used for outlier detection:  https://rdrr.io/cran/dbscan/src/R/LOF.R

This function (from the "dbscan" library) uses the Local Outlier Factor (LOF) algorithm for calculating outliers : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_outlier_factor.

The LOF algorithm is an unsupervised, distance based algorithm that defines outliers in a dataset relative to the "reachability and neighborhood" of an observation. In general, observations that are not "very reachable" with respect to other observations in their neighborhood are considered to be an "outlier". Based on these properties (the user specifies these properties, e.g the neighborhood (denoted by "k") could be "3"), this algorithm assigns a LOF "score" to each point in the dataset. The bigger the LOF score for a given observation, this observation is considered to be more of an outlier.

Now, I am trying to better understand some of the calculations taking place in the `dbscan::lof()` function.

**1)** The basic LOF algorithm can be run on some artificially created data like this:

````
```#load library(dbscan)
par(mfrow = c(1,2))
#generate data
n <- 100
x <- cbind(
  x=runif(10, 0, 5) + rnorm(n, sd=0.4),
  y=runif(10, 0, 5) + rnorm(n, sd=0.4)
  )

### calculate LOF score
lof <- lof(x, k=3)

### distribution of outlier factors
summary(lof)
hist(lof, breaks=10)

### point size is proportional to LOF
plot(x, pch = ".", main = "LOF (k=3)")
points(x, cex = (lof-1)*3, pch = 1, col="red") ```
````

[image]

My question is  : Do larger values of "k" result in fewer outliers being identified (histogram is left-skewed), but those outliers that are identified are more "extreme" (i.e. bigger LOF scores)?

I observed this general pattern, but I am not sure if this trend is reflected in the LOF algorithms code. E.g.

```
#plot LOF results for different values of k

par(mfrow = c(2,2))



### calculate LOF score
lof <- lof(x, k=3)

### distribution of outlier factors
summary(lof)
hist(lof, main = "k = 3",breaks=10)

### calculate LOF score
lof <- lof(x, k=10)

### distribution of outlier factors
summary(lof)
hist(lof, main = "k = 10", breaks=10)

### calculate LOF score
lof <- lof(x, k=20)

### distribution of outlier factors
summary(lof)
hist(lof, main = "k = 20", breaks=10)


### calculate LOF score
lof <- lof(x, k=40)

### distribution of outlier factors
summary(lof)
hist(lof, main = "k = 10", breaks=40)
```

[image]

In the above plots, you can see as the value of "k" increases fewer outliers are being identified. Is this correct?

**2)** Is there an "optimal" way to select a value of "k" for the LOF algorithm? Seeing how the LOF algorithm, it does not seem to me that there is a "optimal" way to select a value of "k". It seems that you must refer to the logic described in **1)** :

1. Bigger values of "k" result in fewer outliers being identified, but
   the outliers identified are more "extreme"
2. Smaller values of "k" result in more outliers being identified, but
   the outliers identified are less "extreme"

Is this correct?

Comment: Does anyone know how to take the answer from this link: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/138675/choosing-a-k-value-for-local-outlier-factor-lof-detection-analysis ... and write the equivalent R code?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding **2)** , I found this stackoverflow post over here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/138675/choosing-a-k-value-for-local-outlier-factor-lof-detection-analysis  :

*" The authors of the paper recommend choosing a minimum k and a maximum k, and for each point, taking the maximum LOF value over each k in that range. They offer several guidelines for choosing the bounds."*

This is my logic of implementing the above into R code:

```
library(dbscan)

#generate data
n <- 100
x <- cbind(
  x=runif(10, 0, 5) + rnorm(n, sd=0.4),
  y=runif(10, 0, 5) + rnorm(n, sd=0.4)
  )

x = data.frame(x)

### calculate LOF score for a range of different "k" values:

lof_10 <- lof(x, k=10)
lof_15 <- lof(x, k=15)
lof_20 <- lof(x, k=20)

#append these lof calculations the original data set:

x$lof_10 = lof_10
x$lof_15 = lof_15
x$lof_20 = lof_20

#as the previous stackoverflow post suggests: for each row, choose the highest LOF value 

x$max_lof = pmax(x$lof_10, x$lof_15, x$lof_20)

#view results:

 head(x)

         x          y    lof_10    lof_15    lof_20   max_lof
1 2.443382  4.2611753 0.9803894 0.9866732 0.9841705 0.9866732
2 2.397454 -0.3732838 1.0527592 1.4638348 1.6008284 1.6008284
3 2.617348  3.0435179 0.9952212 0.9945580 0.9715819 0.9952212
4 3.731156  4.1668976 1.0339001 1.0802826 1.0921033 1.0921033
5 1.103123  1.6642337 1.1260092 1.0773444 1.0650159 1.1260092
6 2.735938  4.3737450 0.9939896 0.9573139 0.9700123 0.9939896
```

Therefore, the LOF score for each row is the value of the "max_lof" column.

Can someone please tell me if interpreted the previous stackoverflow post correctly? Have I also written the R code correctly?

Thanks

Note: I am still not sure about **1)** from my initial question,

*i.e.  Do larger values of "k" result in fewer outliers being identified (histogram is left-skewed), but those outliers that are identified are more "extreme"?*